# Checking for pairs and tripple fittings

Tags: c#, linq

I have this

```
public class Karte
{
    public string value = "";
    //
}

public class mainclass()
{
  bool whatever()
  {
    List<Karte> Karten = new List<Karte>();
    //Add Objects of Karte to Karten with different entries for value
    if (testing)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
}
```

Within testing I want it to return true if there is 3 times the same string and 2 times another string.

Example:

```
Karte-object-number,value
1,1
2,A
3,A
4,7
5,A
6,7
7,9
8,A
```

should return true(AAA and 77)

```
Karte-object-number,value
1,1
2,A
3,A
4,A
5,A
6,A
7,9
8,A
```

should return true(AAA and AA)

```
Karte-object-number,value
1,1
2,A
3,A
4,7
5,M
6,7
7,9
8,F
```

should return false. (AA and 77, two pairs, but no AAA or 777)

Comment: what does it have to do with Linq?

Comment: @MaryamArshi I don't understand your question.

Comment: You put you question under Linq Tag, I don't see any relation between this question and Linq.

Comment: @MaryamArshi That's funny because it has a lot to do with LINQ, actually.

Comment: I think the spec should say "Within testing I want it to return true if there is 3 times the same string and 2 times another *or additional copies of the same* string."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to group by each value and count the number of occurances:

```
var groups = karten
          .GroupBy(k => k.value)
          .Select(group => new { Key = group.Key, Count = group.Count() })
          .ToList();
```

Now you can apply your testing logic:

```
bool testing = (groups.Count == 1 && groups[0].Count >= 5) || (groups.Count >= 2 && groups[0].Count + groups[1].Count >= 5);
```